# Form to Email PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I am new to php and am not quite sure how to do this I am attempting to build a contact form that sends an email currently the HTML I Have for the form is:

```
<section class="mbr-section form1 cid-qL6aon4aVW" id="form1-11">




<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="title col-12 col-lg-8">
            <h2 class="mbr-section-title align-center pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-2">
                MAINTENANCE FORM
            </h2>
            <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle align-center mbr-light pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                Request Maintenance for your unit.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="media-container-column col-lg-8" data-form-type="formoid">


                <form class="mbr-form" action="feedback.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row row-sm-offset">
                        <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="name">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="name-form1-11">Full Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-form-field="Name" required="" placeholder="Full Name" id="name-form1-11">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="email">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="email-form1-11">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-form-field="Email" required="" placeholder="Email" id="email-form1-11">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 multi-horizontal" data-for="phone">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="phone-form1-11">Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" data-form-field="Phone" placeholder="Phone #" id="phone-form1-11">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" data-for="message">
                        <label class="form-control-label mbr-fonts-style display-7" for="message-form1-11">Request</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="message" rows="7" data-form-field="Message" placeholder="Request" id="message-form1-11"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form display-4">SEND FORM</button>
                    </span>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the PHP I have is :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to="email@email.com";

$subject="Shovers.net Maintenance form submission";

$mail_from="from: ".$_POST['email']." \n";

$mail_from .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \n";

$message="<font size=\"2\" face=\"Verdana\"> Here is the message:<br />
".$_POST['comments']."<br />
".$_POST['name']."<br />
".$_POST['email']."</font>";

mail($mail_from,$to,$subject,$comments);

echo "Thanks!";
$TARGET = "/";

    header("Location: $TARGET");
    exit();


}else{
}
?>
```

I can't seem to get this to send to my email and I am not sure why on form submit it currently just goes to the feedback.php page which is blank as it is just the PHP script. Does this need to be running on the actual server for it to work or will it work with xampp and apache/mysql running? If not what do I need to do to get this working?

In addition I am also trying to get it to just reload/stay on that same page but pop up a verification message what am I doing wrong for that?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Probably configuration not done properly for mail() method in php.ini. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php and verify all parameters set correctly.

Alternatively, this is good guide on the setup, will help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function

Comment: " Does this need to be running on the actual server for it to work" yes. unless your running your own mail server locally (unlikely)